# Wordpress: How to get users first and last name in table query?

Tags: wordpress

a friend of mine wrote me a small plugin, which is putting out the users display_name. i can't reach him at the moment, that's why i'm asking here. thx for your advice!

how do i get instead of only users display_name the full name (first name and last name?)

i know functions like `$user->last_name; $user->first_name;` , but not within a mysql query in wordpress..

```
function getEVentRSVPUsers($post_id,$event_rsvp=0){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_rsvp_event   =   $wpdb->prefix."event_rsvp as E"; 
    $query              =   "Select E.user_id,U.display_name from $table_rsvp_event 
                                LEFT JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."users as U   
                                ON  
                                E.user_id = U.ID
                                where 
                                E.post_id = $post_id
                                AND
                                event_rsvp  =   $event_rsvp
                                group by E.user_id
                                ";  
    $results            =   $wpdb->get_results($query); 
    $userlist           =   "";
    if($results){
        $userlist       = "<ul>";
        foreach($results as $result){
            $user_nicename   =  $result->display_name;
            $userlist       .= "<li><strong>$user_nicename</strong></li>";
        }
        $userlist       .= "<ul>";
    }
    return $userlist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this code

```
   $query              =   "Select E.user_id,U.display_name from $table_rsvp_event
```

add first_name and last_name to the query.

```
   $query              =   "Select E.user_id, U.display_name, first_name, last_name from $table_rsvp_event
```

And in

```
   foreach($results as $result){
        $user_nicename   =  $result->display_name;
        $userlist       .= "<li><strong>$user_nicename</strong></li>";
    }
```

change display_name  to first_name and last_name

```
        $user_nicename   =  $result->first_name . " " . $result->last_name;
```

Comment: empty...tried already with query first_name and result->first_name.. aren't first_name and last_name saved in this table?

Comment: Yes. first and last name should be fields in the table. Are the fields different names?